# Check if a regex matched an optional group

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to match an HTTP request line and to fetch the requested item. I have the following  regular expression:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("GET /(\\w+\\.\\w+)? HTTP/1.1");
```

If you check it, you will notice an optional group `(\\w+\\.\\w+)?`. When I send a file, like for example `GET /index.html HTTP/1.1` it works correctly and `matcher.groupCount()` returns `1`. The problem is when I send something like `GET / HTTP/1.1`. I don't know how to check if the group has been matched, since `matcher.groupCount()` returns `1` as well. I suspect that the `groupCount()` function returns the number of groups in the regex regardless of their existence in the parsed String.

Thanks

Comment: I know I could use something like (.*), but I would like to know if this is possible.

Comment: I know there are other options, but I would like to know if it is possible to figure out how many groups where matched. This is just an example :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use optional group here actually. This regex will work better for you:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("GET (/\\S+) HTTP/1\.1");
```

i.e. match & capture everything from first `/` until you hit a space as the `REQUEST URI`.

Remember a web request can contain query parameters also with `?`, `&` etc and `\\w+\\.\\w+` is not a good regex to match them all.